# Rotating an empty game object on click and drag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have many objects in a scene that I have logically grouped together inside an empty game object as a layer.

If the user clicks anywhere in the scene and moves their mouse horizontally I want that empty game object to rotate around the y-axis so that all the objects inside it rotate too.

I successfully applied a rotation script (see below) to a cube, but the same script doesn't seem to work when applied to an empty game object. I tried adding a box collider to it thinking it would make it register the click, but it hasn't helped.

Any idea where I might be going wrong? Am I taking the wrong approach here?

For reference, this is my drag script:

```
void OnMouseDrag() {
  float rotationX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 20f * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

  transform.RotateAround(Vector3.up, -rotationX);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the user clicks **anywhere** in the scene and moves their mouse
>   horizontally I want that empty game object to rotate around the y-axis
>   so that all the objects inside it rotate too. but the same script doesn't seem to work when applied to an empty game object

The `OnMouseDrag` function doesn't work **anywhere** on the screen. It will only work when you want to detect click on a `GUIElement` or an object with a `Collider`. It's more like you just want to detect when the mouse is held down anywhere on the screen. The `Input.GetMouseButton` function should be used if that's the case. It should also be used in the `Update` function so that the code will run every frame and use `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")` to obtain the drag speed.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        float rotationX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 20f * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
        transform.RotateAround(Vector3.up, -rotationX);
    }
}
```